# Mount doesn't give write permission to user

Tags: permissions, mount

I just created a new ext4 filesystem on a new drive and I am trying to mount it manually:

```
mount /dev/sdc1 a
```

it does mount correctly, but then only root seems to have write permissions. How can I give write permissions to my user as well?

Comment: Is this a permanent thing? If so, you can add the drive to your `/etc/fstab` with the `user` option activated.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal behavior - `mount` doesn't give write permissions at all. The write permissions are controlled by the permissions bits on the directory in the filesystem (i.e. after it's mounted). To manage who can read and write from/to this filesystem, just use the normal `chown` and `chmod` tools.

Comment: Why does mount change the ownership of the directory? Initially this a directory was owned by my user with write permission on it.

Comment: @Grzenio mount temporarily overlays the directory `a` with the `/` directory of the filesystem that has been mounted. `a`'s owner, its permissions, even all of its contents, are all hidden. When you unmount the filesystem, you can access `a` just as it was before.

Comment: The directory `a` prior to the mount is a completely different item than the filesystem at `a` after the mount.

Comment: "mount doesn't give write permissions at all." For the sake of completeness, some filesystems (the ones which don't support Unix permissions, e. g. _fat_ and _vfat_) may be provided `uid`, `gid` and some `?mask` options through `mount` to control access.

Comment: If you just need to view files, and the mounted filesystem is read-only, just open a GUI file manager as `root`, [as I mention here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745998/114401).

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Plotnick said, `mount` just overlays a directory in your system with the contents of `/` on the attached drive.

To circumnavigate this and as an expansion to John's answer, you can try

```
chmod -R -rwxrw-rw a
```

or

```
chmod -R 755 a
```

depending on your preference. The command will change all files in `a` to give you RW permissions.

Alternatively, if `ls -l` reports that root is the owner:

```
chown -R <your name here> a
```

would make you the owner of all the files in `a`.

*`chmod` and `chown` with `-R` can mess up some intentional permissions modifications on files, so do exercise caution when executing such commands.*

Comment: Shouldn't that be `chmod -R -rwxrw-rw- a`? (with a final `-` to say unprivileged users can't execute the file.)

Comment: The second command and the third combined worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the mounted filesystem is read only, such as a MacBook Apple Filesystem (APFS) mounted with [`apfs-fuse`](https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse) on an Ubuntu LiveUSB, you *can't* use `chown` to change the owner. In that case, just open a root file manager window and view the files through that.

Ex:

```bash
# the default Ubuntu file manager: nautilus
sudo nautilus

# the pretty one (https://askubuntu.com/a/1173861/327339): nemo
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
sudo nemo
```