# XRDP won't allow connections automatically on startup (CentOS7)

Tags: centos, xrdp, rdp

I've got XRDP installed on two of my CentOS7 machines, on one of them , XRDP works fine and allows connections straight away from when the machine is booted up. However, on the other, I have to boot up, then enter the commands:

```
systemctl stop xrdp
systemctl start xrdp
systemctl enable xrdp
```

Then it allows connections for about an hour, then I have to use those commands again....

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The `systemctl enable xrdp` should set the `xrdp` service to start up automatically at boot time. If that is getting undone, it suggests the system may be under some sort of automated management (think Ansible, SaltStack, Puppet or something similar) that is enforcing some settings at intervals of about an hour, including the fact that `xrdp` should be shut down. Talk to your fellow system administrators.

Comment: @telcoM I am my only administrator :D

Comment: Alternatively, if the system is exposed to traffic from the internet, XRDP might be crashing because various automated malware on the internet are running portscans and Windows RDP exploits against it. In that case, you really should set your firewall to block traffic to XRDP's port from any untrusted networks ASAP.

Comment: @telcoM How can I configure my firewall to do that?

Comment: I don't know what firewall you're using, if any. If you are using CentOS 7's default `firewalld`, you have already had to do something with it to enable access to `xrdp` from the network. But at the basic level, `firewalld` only allows enabling/disabling access to services by network interface. If you have just one NIC in use, you'll need the more advanced [rich rules](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html) to specify that `xrdp` access should be allowed from your own IP subnet(s) only.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks so much - do you know anything about fstab mounts? [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591547/permanent-network-drive-mount-in-fstab-not-working)

Comment: @telcoM Final question - you're being so helpful! - Do you know how to set something to execute on logout/shutdown? - I want to umount -a on logout. [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591410/run-script-at-logout-shutdown-in-centos7)