# Run script at logout/shutdown in CentOS7

Tags: centos, scripting, startup, logout

I have a couple of scripts that I would like to run on logout/shutdown and can't find the place to add them. I use `mate-session-properties` frequently to add scripts to run on startup - where is the opposite held?

Thanks - (I run CentOS7)

Comment: In the comments of another question, you asked me to look at this. But sorry, CentOS's default desktop is GNOME and I'm more of a KDE guy. However, I'm sure it is possible - [these questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=gnome+logout+script) might have helpful answers.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks anyway - I'm running MATE :)